# Add link to top menu using xml magento

Tags: xml, magento-1.7

I try to add my custom link to top menu using xml but it didn't work.I used this code before and work fine but now i am stuck with it.My xml code is :

```
<default>
          <reference name="top.links">           
            <block type="articles/links" name="articles"/>
           <action method="addLinkBlock" ><blockName>articles</blockName></action>
        </reference> 
                <reference name="footer_links">
                     <block type="articles/links" name="articles"/>
            <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>articles</blockName></action>
                </reference>

    </default>
```

And my block code is :

```
class My_Articles_Block_Links extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $html ='';      

        if(Mage::helper('articles')->getArticlesEnable()){


        if(in_array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(),Mage::helper('articles')->getscopeid())){

                $html.= '<li><a  href="'.Mage::helper('articles')->getUrl().'">Articles</a></li>';    
                return $html;
            }
        }

        return $html;
    }



}.
```

The Block code is fine and tested.only issue with the xml code.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you have action tag
it would check for function in action from `addActionLayoutHandles()`

So, instead of overidding `_toHtml()`
simply add a function

`function addLinkBlock(){
        $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
        $parentBlock->addLink('whatever link you want to add');
    }`

Comment: I try like this 
protected function addLinkBlock(){ 
     
        $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock(); 
        $parentBlock->addLink('<li><a href="mahmood">asif</a></li>'); 
        return $parentBlock;
    }.But not show any link on top menu. any idea what's wrong ??